# looking for database with companies and its SIC codes

Tags: data-request, usa, industry

I am building model to predict that is something similar to SICCODE.com, in search if I give "apple inc" as input, it gives me all related to apple with its sic codes and location.

```
apple inc       cupertino,ca, 95014        us
apple bank for savings      newyork, NY,10172       us
```

I looking for a database which contains all company names in US and its location and its SIC codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data exists but it is unlikely to be open.  From the [U.S. Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/faqs/faqs.html#q13) (recall there is a [crosswalk](https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/concordances/concordances.html) between SIC and NAICS codes)

> 13. Can I get a NAICS code or other statistical data for a specific company?
>
> Title 13, U.S. Code, Section 9 (a) prohibits the U.S. Census
> Bureau from releasing information on a specific business including
> NAICS codes. Visit our [Data Protection and Privacy Policy Web site](https://www.census.gov/about/policies/privacy/data_protection/federal_law.html) to
> obtain more information on Title 13. There are a number of private
> research firms that provide NAICS codes and data for specific
> companies, often for a fee. The U.S. Census Bureau cannot verify the
> accuracy of the codes or data provided by these companies.

An example of such a firm would be [NAICS Association](https://www.naics.com/company-lookup-tool/).